# Select related rows in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I have related tables (table train_schedule have departute_station_id and arrival_station_id) linked on Station:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDnNt.png)

I want select records from train_schedule with stations name:

```
 $trainsTchedule = TrainSchedule::find()
            ->joinWith('getArrivalStation')
            ->joinWith('getDepartuteStation()')
            ->all();
```

In TrainSchedule class:

```
 /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getArrivalStation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Station::className(), ['id' => 'arrival_station_id']);
    }
```

And

```
  /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDepartuteStation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Station::className(), ['id' => 'departute_station_id']);
    }
```

Error:

> Relation names are case sensitive. app\models\TrainSchedule has a
>   relation named "arrivalStation" instead of "ArrivalStation".

Howe get data wrom linked tables?

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you, it might help others looking for the same solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your relations correctly but, you are calling them incorrectly. Your relation

- `getArrivalStation` should be specified as `arrivalStation`
- `getDepartuteStation()` should be `departuteStation`

when specifying in the [`joinWith`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail), and you need to provide an `array` if you need to specify multiple relations when calling `joinWith` as currently your second call `->joinWith('getDepartuteStation()')` is overriding the previous one `->joinWith('getArrivalStation')`.

So the query should look like below

```
$trainsTchedule = TrainSchedule::find()
    ->joinWith(['arrivalStation','departuteStation'])
    ->all();
```

You should read about [Working with Relational Data](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data)